# Max modulus Constrained Optimization

Tags: inequality, optimization, complex-numbers, nonlinear-optimization

Let $z_1,z_2\ldots,z_n\in\mathbb{C}$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{z_i^j}=1\quad,\:\forall j=1,2,\ldots,n-1$$
and 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}z_i^n=q\qquad\textrm{ with } |q|<1.$$
I am interested in finding a bound on the maximum modulus
$$\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\{|z_i|\}$$
Specifically, if conditions can be imposed on $|q|$ such that these bounds are less that 1 i.e. all $z_i$ lie within the unit circle.

Comment: @metamorphy Thank you for your comment. I am looking for something more elegant and simple. Note that the points $z_1,\cdots,z_n$ are solutions of the equation $z^n-z^{n-1}+(1-q)=0$. Thus, Schur-Cohn theorem can be used to find necessary and sufficient condition so that all $z_i$ are within the unit circle but I do not want to calculate all these lengthy determinants. I am just searching for a sufficient condition on this.

Comment: @RTJ: in order to find the number of roots of $z^n-z^{n-1}+(1-q)$ inside the unit circle you just need a numerical approximation of $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\|z\|=1}\frac{n z^{n-1}-(n-1)z^{n-2}}{z^{n}-z^{n-1}+(1-q)}\,dz$$

Comment: and in a geometric framework, given the relation between the topological degree of a curve and the number of roots of a polynomial in a the circle, you just need to find sufficient conditions on $q$ such that the origin lies inside the inner loop of the parametric curve $\cos(n\theta)-\cos((n-1)\theta)+1-q,\sin(n\theta)-\sin((n-1)\theta)$. $1-\frac{C}{n}\leq q< 1$ for some positive constant $C$ should suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reformulating, we want some conditions on $q$ such that all the roots of the polynomial $z^n-z^{n-1}+(1-q)$ lie inside the unit circle. This is pretty much the same exercise appearing at page 127 of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view), serving as an introduction to the original proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra provided by Gauss. Let $\tau=1-q$. Given the relation between the topological degree of curves and the number of roots of polynomials inside disks, it is enough to understand which values of $\tau$ ensure that the origin belongs to the inner loop of the parametric curve
$$\gamma(s)=\left(\cos(ns)-\cos((n-1)s)+\tau,\sin(ns)-\sin((n-1)s)\right).$$
For instance, here it is our curve for $n=7$ and $\tau=0$:

[image]

The upper part of the inner loop is given by values of $s$ between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2n+1}$. If we want the origin to be enclosed by the inner loop, we need that $0<\tau<2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4n+2}\right)$.
If we allow complex $\tau$s,

$$ \left\|\tau-\sin\left(\tfrac{\pi}{4n+2}\right)\right\|\leq \tfrac{1}{2}\,\sin\left(\tfrac{\pi}{4n+2}\right)$$
is a sufficient condition for $x^{n}-x^{n-1}+\tau$ to have all its zeroes inside the unit disk.

Comment: Great answer, thank you Jack!